# jquery script not working first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I access a specific page I have at the start of a day, no data will show. After I refresh the same page, the data appears as it should. If I were to access the same page an hour later the data will still be shown. However, come the next day, the same will happen. No data when I access the page first time, but it comes after a refresh.

The page in question uses a jquery script with an ajax call.

The script itself is used in a Sharepoint 2010 environment and uses ListData.svc to fetch data (name, id, type and soforth), and getting the actual data doesn't seem to be an issue (at least when I refresh).

Anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.parent.location.href.slice(window.parent.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }

    var pTypeval = getUrlVars()["projectType"];
    $('#projTypeHeader').append(unescape(pTypeval));

    $.ajax({
        url: "/../Projects/1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projectlist?$select=ID,Projectname,ProjectTypeValue,ProjectHeading,PublishInfoscreen&$filter=(ProjectTypeValue%20eq%20%27" + pTypeval + "%27)%20and%20(PublishInfoscreen%20eq%20true)",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#projectRow').empty();

            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                var itemExist = false;
                $.each($('.projectRow').find('h1'), function (index1, item1) {
                    if (item1.innerHTML == item.ProjectHeading) {
                        itemExist = true;
                        $(item1).parent().append("<h3><a id=" + item.ID + " class='projectLink' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + item.Projectname+ "</a></h3>");

                    }
                });
                if (itemExist == false)
                    $('.projectRow').append("<div class='projectHeadingDiv left'><li><h1>" + item.ProjectHeading + "</h1><h3><a id='" + item.ID + "' class='projectLink'  href='javascript:void(0)'>" + item.Projectname+ "</a></h3></div>");
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

**Update:**
As per the comments, I tried moving the function getUrlVars() outside the document.ready, this did not help.
However, I tried using a different browser this morning and on the first fetch I got this error:

Site on intranet says:
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\r\n\"error\": {\r\n"code\":
\"\", \"message\": {\r\n\"lang\": \"en-US\", \"value": \Type
'Microsoft.Sharepoint.DataService.ProjectlistItem' does not have a property named 'ID'. \"\r\n}\r\n}\r\r}","status":
400,"statusText":"error"}

Refreshed the page and the data appears. It would seem like on the first GET, it can't find the items in the list, but after a second GET, it works just fine. Any suggestions why this could be?

Comment: try to put `getUrlVars()` function outside `document.ready`

Comment: My guess would be the server goes to sleep at night and you waking it up in the morning but the first call gets a timeout. Can you post what the error response ?

Comment: Thank you for responses. I am unable to get the error response until tomorrow morning, but I will post here once I have it. I will also try to put the getUrlVars() function outside of document.ready.

Comment: @MotiKorets I have updated the original post with the error message I got

Comment: So it seems your problem is have more to do with SharePoint than with jQuery. I'll suggest tag  the question appropriately. Check the server for any sleep configuration.

Comment: Please check the Caching: is the jquery lib cached for ONE day ? if yes it means that after getting it (first time) you no more load it the whole day. How/where in your page do you load the jquery lib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint app pools recycle every night. Because of this, the first hit of the day on a SharePoint site can take some time for everything to spin up. Some people run this powershell script to continuously keep the SP server active. This should resolve the lag on the webservice you are hitting in the mornings.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/03/12/sfsgfasg.aspx